# EF Core relationships include or exclude child entities

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core

Striped from other code, I have a simple schema and its respective classes:

```
public class FormsContext : DbContext
{
     public FormsContext(DbContextOptions<FormsContext> options) : base( options ) { }

     public virtual DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder ) { }
}

public class Template
{
    public Template()
    {
        Forms = new HashSet<Form>();
        TemplatePages = new HashSet<TemplatePage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Form> Forms { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TemplatePage> TemplatePages { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public Form() { }
    //...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class TemplatePage
{
    public TemplatePage() { }
    //...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}
```

I load the entity (e.g. id=1000) using

```
Template template = _context.Templates.Where( t => t.Id == 1000 ).Single();
```

Inspecting the 'template' object in the debugger, I see that the object has  the Forms collection loaded, but the TemplatePages collection is empty.

I don't understand why is this happening. Neither why the Forms collection is loaded (I haven't declared any relationship in the context) nor why TemplatePages is not loaded.

Comment: 1) Forms can be loaded earlier and EF Core just connects them. 2) Show generated SQL in question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv 1) yes, the forms are indeed loaded earlier. 2) how do I generate the SQL query?

Comment: Just enable EF Core logging and check what is generated.

Comment: Add `AsNoTracking()` to your query and `Forms` should be not connected.